# Apache Beam - use output of one aggregation in another aggregation

Tags: python, apache-beam, distributed-computing

I am new to Apache Beam, coming over from PySpark's dataframe API. I'm having trouble using the output of one beam calculation in another beam calculation. Basically, I want to perform an aggregation that yields one value (such as an average) and use the result of this aggregation as a python primitive (e.g. a float) in a subsequent aggregation. For example:

```
import apache_beam as beam

DATA = [
  beam.Row(val="hello"),
  beam.Row(val="stackoverflow,"),
  beam.Row(val="plz"),
  beam.Row(val="halp"),
]

with beam.Pipeline() as pipe:
  graph = pipe | beam.Create(DATA)
  average_word_length = (graph 
    | "Get lengths" >> beam.ParDo(lambda row: beam.Row(length=len(row.val)))
    | "Compute mean" >> beam.combiners.Mean.Globally()
    | "Print avg" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
  # average_word_lengths is a PCollection with only one value: 6.5

  (graph 
    | "Compute metric" >> beam.ParDo(lambda row: beam.Row(newval=len(row.val)/average_word_length)) # fails here
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

This fails with a TypeError because I'm trying to divide an int by a PCollection... is there a way to extract the one float value from the `average_word_length` PCollection and use it as a float in the next aggregation? If not, how do I achieve something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `Side Input`. Here's the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) about them.

Working solution (note that I removed one of the prints so that there's an actual output there):

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import pvalue


DATA = [
  beam.Row(val="HOPE"),
  beam.Row(val="THIS,"),
  beam.Row(val="WORKS"),
  beam.Row(val="BLABLABLA"),
]

with beam.Pipeline() as pipe:
  graph = pipe | beam.Create(DATA)
  average_word_length = (graph 
    | "Get lengths" >> beam.ParDo(lambda row: beam.Row(length=len(row.val)))
    | "Compute mean" >> beam.combiners.Mean.Globally()
  )
  # average_word_lengths is a PCollection with only one value: 6.5

  (graph 
    | "Compute metric" >> beam.ParDo(lambda row, side: beam.Row(newval=len(row.val)/side), 
                                                          side=pvalue.AsSingleton(average_word_length)) # fails here
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Comment: Wow, perfect, thank you! I thought I had read the whole programming guide ... but I missed this!