# How to use Pcollection List length & values to partition Pcollection?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have dynamically fetched the data list from BigQuery, and transformed it into a so-called beam list, using a map transform I have calculated its length, now I want to use this `length` and `list` to `partition` the larger `PCollection` and then run some transformations on individual partitions fanning out the operation.
I am getting stuck on passing the `length` & `list` to Partition Transformation. Beam only allows the processing output PCollections via a ParDo function side inputs, using pvalue submodule.
I am looking for a workaround to do the above.

What can work here?

- Side Inputs
- Singletons
- Custom PTransforms
- Custom ParDo

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        sites_list = (
            pipeline
            | "Get site_id from D_Sites Table"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="SELECT DISTINCT(site_id) FROM `dataset.D_Sites`;",
                use_standard_sql=True,
                project="myproject",
            )
            | "Get Keys" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x["site_id"])
            | "Combine to list" >> beam.combiners.ToList()
        )

        site_list_len = sites_list | "Calculate Site List length" >> beam.Map(len)

        edge_data = (
            pipeline
            | "Query and Filter Edge data"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query=special_query,
                use_standard_sql=True,
                project="myproject",
            )
            | "Partition"
            >> beam.Partition(
                lambda data, num_partitions: sites_list.index(data["site_id"]),
                site_list_len,
            )
            | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

The `sites_list` PCollection will have a list inside it, for example below:

```py
["S10001","S10002","S10023","S10003","A10012"]
```

Considering the above example if we have the above list in PCollection then we will use these items and the length of the site list to partition the data retrieved from the major query in `edge_data` PCollection. The partition step will partition the edge data into 5 different PCollections and I will write these PCollections as CSVs into GCS.

This will be added after the partitions are done:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(sites_list):
    d[i] | f"Map to CSV strings {x}" >> beam.Map(
        lambda x: ",".join(x.values())
    ) | f"Write to CSV {x}" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
        f"gs://test-bucket/partition-test/{x}",
        file_name_suffix=".csv",
        header="col1,name,duration,...",
    )
```

Comment: Use Side Inputs, here you have an example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769113/apache-beam-use-output-of-one-aggregation-in-another-aggregation/71770440#71770440

Comment: Can you share your solution? - I tried using side inputs but it doesn't get the original integer value

Comment: But how will the partition map work here with side inputs?

Comment: Can you give us a mock for the 2 inputs from Bigquery and an example of the expected output please ?

Comment: Added some more description about where I wish to take this forward. The above approach works with a hard-coded list...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to dynamically partition your PCollection, because it varies in size? I think this is not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73394450/16622985).
If you would know the maximum amount of partitions you could hard-code your 'worst case' scenario, but that wouldn't be that nice I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out, you need side inputs here. You'd do something like this:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        sites_list = beam.pvalue.AsList(
            pipeline
            | "Get site_id from D_Sites Table"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query="SELECT DISTINCT(site_id) FROM `dataset.D_Sites`;",
                use_standard_sql=True,
                project="myproject",
            )
            | "Get Keys" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x["site_id"])
        )

        edge_data = (
            pipeline
            | "Query and Filter Edge data"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query=special_query,
                use_standard_sql=True,
                project="myproject",
            )
            | "Partition"
            >> beam.Partition(
                lambda data, sites: sites[data["site_id"]],
                sites=sites_list)
            | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

Where `sites_list` is a side input to the "Partition" step.

Comment: This is not how Apache beam works...
Passings inputs to the PTranform is quite tricky than it seems, it doesn't accept native python data types like list, dict, etc and in case you want to do that the input has to be fetched during the runtime before it creates a DAG to be executed

Comment: I have finally scraped the above approach since it is not feasible and Apache beam doesn't support it. At the same time, I created a parametrized reusable template which is selected and executed by some logic residing in the Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: could you share your solution for dynamic partition @K1Shah ?

Comment: I executed the sites_list query in GCloud Functions, where I have the list for which I must submit the dataflow job. I abstracted the dataflow job submission by templating the Dflow graph with a few parameters, selecting which saved template to use, and now for every site in the list, a separate job is submitted.